# Running .exe from byte array

Tags: c#

In my application I am attempting to run an exe from its byte array, I do it like this:

```
private static void RunFromBytes(byte[] bin)
        {

            Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
            // search for the Entry Point
            MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
            if (method != null)
            {
                // create an istance of the Startup form Main method
                object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
                // invoke the application starting point
                method.Invoke(o, null);
            }
        }
```

However I get this error when I try this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly '49150 bytes
>   loaded from mybbClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.

on this line:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
```

The byte[] is from a .net application and works fine if I write it to disk and run it from there. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your program and the bytes are both compiled for 32bit or both for 64bit? A mismatch would also cause this error.

Comment: you god. You're right. My bad, it simply fell through my head to check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) for this exception, one common possible cause is mismatching 32bit and 64bit assemblies. The exact wording is:

> A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains 32-bit features or resources.

Make sure that there is no target platform mismatch, as that would prevent the assembly from being loaded properly.